# How do I rearrange nested Pandas DataFrame columns?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

In the DataFrame below, I want to rearrange the nested columns - i.e. to have 'region_sea' appearing before 'region_inland'

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'state': ['WA', 'CA', 'NY', 'NY', 'CA', 'CA', 'WA' ]
                    , 'region': ['region_sea', 'region_inland', 'region_sea', 'region_inland', 'region_sea', 'region_sea', 'region_inland',]
                    , 'count': [1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 4]
                    , 'income': [100, 200, 300, 400, 600, 400, 300]
                   }
                 )

df = df.pivot_table(index='state', columns='region', values=['count', 'income'], aggfunc={'count': 'sum', 'income': 'mean'})
df
```

[image]

I tried the code below but it's not working...any idea how to do this? Thanks

```
df[['count']]['region_sea', 'region_inland']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sort_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html#pandas.DataFrame.sort_values) to sort it. However, as it is nested columns, it will replace income and count too.

```
df.sort_index(axis='columns', level=0, ascending=False, inplace=True)
```

If you don't want replace income/count, than it will not give common header for both.

```
df.sort_index(axis='columns', level='region', ascending=False, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Hi - this doesn't quite work as I don't want to sort it based on alphabetical order - I need it to be custom e.g. I might need the order to be 'region_sea', 'region_beach', and 'region_inland'. Any ideas how to do this?